# I want to check the DNS value from my system

Tags: python

I want to check the DNS value from my system.

If the command goes wrong, the error should be stored in a different variable.

This is what I have so far:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', '"to stdout"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)

stdout_value = proc.communicate()
print '\tstdout:', repr(stdout_value)

subprocess.call('echo #user', shell=True)
#subprocess.check_call('echo #HOME', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

It captures errorcode, stdout and stderr from a command you passed as an argument :
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

```
def get_exitcode_stdout_stderr(cmd):

    """
    Execute the external command and get its exitcode, stdout and stderr.
    """
    args = shlex.split(cmd)

    proc = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    exitcode = proc.returncode
    #
    return exitcode, out, err

cmd = "..."  # arbitrary external command, e.g. "python mytest.py"
exitcode, out, err = get_exitcode_stdout_stderr(cmd)
```

For your need, I think you can use a python module to get what you want instead of using the bash cmd line. For example, to get your fully qualified domain name you can use :

```
socket.getfqdn()
```

Comment: if I have these kind of data. And I want only 40035FC8 
40027C5C
40010044
40010044
40035FC8   from this file . what is the logic  *   D:40035FC8 wr-long         00000008 \\core0\Global\u4TimeHiCnt         1.000us
  *    D:40027C5C rd-byte               00 *core0\Global\Ypf_OILL_OilLvlOn   20.342us
  *    D:40010044 rd-word             0FE2 *l\u2SAD_OILLVS_RecoveryCounter    0.160us
  *    D:40010044 wr-word             0FE1 *l\u2SAD_OILLVS_RecoveryCounter    0.040us
  *    D:40035FC8 wr-long         00000008 \\core0\Global\u4TimeHiCnt         1.000us